# Генерация персональной ссылки с GUID

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, guid

Разрабатываю веб-проект на ASP.NET.

**Идея**: автоматически генерировать персональную ссылку на страницу, в адресе которой будет располагаться GUID.
В итоге сгенерированная ссылка на страницу будет выглядеть
`mysite/NewClient/353d451b-11d6-40fc-a37a-8b9fbabab88a`

На странице будут расположены некоторые поля для заполнения, которые после нажатия на кнопку подтверждения вместе с GUID-ссылкой отправятся в БД.

Хочу понять, как сделать генерацию такой ссылки и возможно ли это вообще.

Буду рад любым советам.

Comment: `var link = $"mysite/NewClient/{Guid.NewGuid()}";`? Ну или там `var clientId = Guid.NewGuid(); var link = $"mysite/NewClient/{clientId}";`, а то вам же надо сохранять Id в базу, да?

Comment: Если вы форму отправлять собрались, это же POST, зачем этот GUID в ссылке? Вставьте его как hidden инпут а саму форму при отдаче HTML страницы браузеру, и он прилетит к вам вместе со всеми данными обратно.

Comment: Да, действительно, это подходит.
Я ещё не полностью освоил технологию.
Благодарю за помощь!